# When the number of roots of a matrix polynomial is finite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let $p(W)$ be a matrix polynomial $p(W) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i W^i$ where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and  $W \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ and symmetric.

It is known that certain polynomials like $W^n =\mathbb{0}_{m \times m}$ has infinite many roots.

My question is : When the matrix polynomial $p(W)$, has a finite number of roots?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ Juan Alvarado , I wonder if we read the same question. Is $p$ a real polynomial ?  Is $W$ a symmetric real matrix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never.  Take any polynomial $p $ (of degree at least two) with roots $\lambda_1, \ldots,\lambda_m $. Form $$D=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 &0&\cdots&0\\ 0&\lambda_2 &\cdots&0
\\ 0&0&\ddots &\vdots\\0&0&\cdots&\lambda_m
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now, for every invertible matrix $S $, the matrix $SDS^{-1} $ is a root of $p $, since $$p (SDS^{-1})=Sp (D)S^{-1}. $$

Comment: Dear Martin, many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad I could help!